# Hide ListBoxItems not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a Textbox and a ListBox

```
<TextBox FontSize="12pt" Text="{Binding NameFilter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<ListBox x:Name="EmployeeList" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

The Property of my ViewModel

```
public string NameFilter
{
    get { return _nameFilter; }
    set { 
        _nameFilter = value;
        FilterEmployees();
    }
}
```

FilterEmployees set the Property IsVisible of each Employee to true or false.

I have two Problems:

1.) 
My Setter gets called after each user input and my EmployeeList gets filtered.

```
this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.EmployeeList);
```

Gets called. But I see no updates to my list.

2.)
When I manually Update my List (through another function) the Items dissapear. But they never reapear. My filter set everything to IsVisible=true, when the input string is empty (checked it inside the debugger). But not UI update happens.

What am I missing?! I used this answer, but that seems not to be my problem, since it works if I trigger another Action inside my program that updates the list: 
[WPF - hiding listbox items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697380/wpf-hiding-listbox-items)

EDIT:
I am sorting my Items (actually moving them inside the ObsservableCollection). This way the changes get visible (Employees are hidden). But this just works with hiding, they never reaper.

It seems like the whole stuff gets triggered to late. I want only employees with a "m" inside their name. I have to manually refresh the List two times. Sometimes there are still some Users left, who don't have a "m" inside their name.

Comment: Post `FilterEmployees()` so we can see what you're doing.  On a side note, there are also more elegant ways of filtering using something like Reactive (Rx) and they have a good tutorial on filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the bound collection of List through CollectionView. Your implementation can be as follows : Get CollectionView for ListBox's ItemsSource and define the filter delegate. Using CollectionView and Filter you are not updating the actual `ItemSource` but putting a filter for what to show based on filter predicate.

```
private void FilterEmployees()
        {
            ICollectionView items = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(EmployeeList);
            if (items != null)
            {
                items.Filter = SearchFilter;
            }
        }
```

You can store as the CollectionView member variable so that you don't need to get the CollectionView again and again

```
public bool SearchFilter(object filterObject)
        {
           var filter = filterObject as <<List Box item type>>;
            if (filter == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

             <<Your search logic here.......>>        
}
```

Also, the type of EmployeeList should be ObservableCollection which I found in your edit that you did that.

Now, question here about --- do you have to search on each key stroke or you want to delay the search so that it allows user to type. So to implement this you can create a attach/dependency property to define a delay so that search function will be invoked after defined duration. You have follow the approach mentioned in this [link](https://mahowling.wordpress.com/2014/07/31/wpf-search-text-box-for-mvvm/).

Comment: Wow! This makes things really easy! Thank you very much for the tip with the CollectionView. Works like a charm. Searching on every KeyStroke works pretty well (I just have 15-20 objects in the list).