# How do I truly hide a ListViewItem without destroying my theme?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listviewitem

My issue seems to be one that others have as well, as I've found a few other questions that are similar (e.g. [WPF - hiding listbox items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697380/wpf-hiding-listbox-items)). In that particular question/answer, I've gotten further than anything else I've found combined. The problem I'm facing is that when I implement the `DataTrigger` as it is in the answer there (slightly modified for `ListView` as opposed to `ListBox`), I get the proper collapsing of the item, but for certain things, my theme appears to be reverted to the defaults instead of using my [ModernUI](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/) styling.

Here is what I've added to my `ListView` in order to get the collapsed items to truly be collapsed:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility}" Value="Collapsed">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Here is an example of the items filtered ***before*** adding the above:
[image: Before the <Style/>]

(notice the orange hover of an item that's not supposed to be there)

Here is an example of the items filtered ***after*** adding the above:
[image: After the <Style/>]

(notice the hover/selection indicator is now somehow blue, and my text fields no longer size appropriately)

Any help that anyone can provide will be much appreciated, and thanks already for taking the time to read this.

Side-note: Please don't just tell me to use the `CollectionView` to filter. I spent the majority of my day yesterday fighting with that, and because of using a `BindingList<>` instead of an `ObservableCollection<>`, it simply won't work for my situation.

Comment: Side note: Why are you using a BindingList in WPF?

Comment: Because, based on other suggestions found here, my custom class bubbling up changes through the binding was able to be implemented with a single event, as opposed to jumping through many hoops that I did not understand. I'm pretty new to WPF, so I'm sure it wouldn't be difficult for others, but the `BindingList<>` was a solution that worked (and I'm not building this for Silverlight).

Comment: I can't help much in your specific question but AFAIK BindingList is for WindowsForms and ObservableCollection for WPF. I'd say you'll miss collection changes if using a BindingList

Comment: Add the `BasedOn` attribute on this style so that is inherits the theme's style.

Comment: @LuisFilipe Nope. Functionally it works perfectly well. My only issue is with the DataTrigger restyling my items.

Comment: @MikeEason Okay, so please don't shoot, but I tried using the `BasedOn` yesterday, but I have no idea what to actually base it on. This is the problem I typically have with using third-party stuff (especially stuff I'm not fluent with; aka WFP). Is there a way I can find what's *currently* styling something, so that maybe I can get it from there, or do I require an intimate knowledge of the MordernUI framework?

Comment: Hmm, how about `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}"`. That should base it on whatever the default style of `ListViewItem` is. I haven't tried it using your example but it's worth a shot.

Comment: You can use https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: @LuisFilipe Thanks much! I will get right on that.

Comment: @MikeEason You are my hero! Please make that comment an answer so I can give you some much deserved answer points you beautiful, beautiful man.

Comment: Haha no problem. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `ModernUI` framework overrides the default style of the `ListViewItem`, however you are overriding this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
```

Now your style becomes the new *default* style for a `ListViewItem`. To fix this, use the `BasedOn` attribute to **inherit** the `ModernUI` style.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
```

The code above simply inherits the default `ListViewItem` style (which has been overridden by `ModernUI`).