# ListView item visibility based on boolean

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, visibility

I am trying to filter ListView Items based on input text, and because the selection is removed, I am trying to set visibilty to invisible based on a boolean(I hope this wont remove the selection of items)

I used some older posts to create this code, but I can't figure out why it isn't working:

```
 <ListView x:Name="osebe_listView" Margin="0,0,40,0"  SelectionMode="Multiple"  SelectionChanged="osebe_listView_SelectionChanged" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">

            <ListView.Resources>

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding visible}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1AFFFFFF" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ColumnDefinition}">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="10"/>
                </Style>

            </ListView.Resources>

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Naziv podjetja" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding nazivPodjetja}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Ime" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ime}" Width="25"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Priimek" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding priimek}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Naslov" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding naslov}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Pošta" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding posta}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Mobilna številka" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding mobilnaSt}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Stacionarna številka" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding stacionarnaSt}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="E-naslov" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding eMail}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Skupina" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding skupina}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Text filter method(which is working fine):

```
  private void isci_tb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (isci_tb.Text == "search") return;
            string s = isci_tb.Text;
            if (isci_tb.Text == "")
            {
                foreach (Oseba o in seznamOseb)
                {
                    //osebe_listView.Items.Add(o);
                    o.visible = true;
                }
            }
            //else
            //{
          //  osebe_listView.Items.Clear();
                foreach (Oseba o in seznamOseb)
                {
                    if(! (contejns(o.ime, s) || contejns(o.priimek, s) || contejns(o.mobilnaSt.ToString(), s) || contejns(o.posta, s) || contejns(o.nazivPodjetja, s) || contejns(o.stacionarnaSt.ToString(), s) || contejns(o.naslov, s) || contejns(o.eMail, s)))
                    {
                    o.visible = false;
                    }
                }
            //}
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

I found the [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697380/wpf-hiding-listbox-items)

Note that I am not using any data binding. What am I missing?

Comment: Does the Oseba class implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: In the link he is using `<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>`, can't find that in your code. The `o.visible` doesn't do anything, i guess..

Comment: it does not. How can I implement it? I thought that setting property like that is enough since I didn't find any additional code in that post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `Oseba` class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raises the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `visible` property:

```
public class Oseba : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isVisible;
    public bool visible
    {
        get { return _isVisible; }
        set { _isVisible = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("visible"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This is required for the data trigger in your `ListViewItem` style to get triggered dynamically.

You should also set the `ItemContainerStyle` property of the `ListView` to your custom style with the `DataTrigger`:

```
<ListView x:Name="osebe_listView" Margin="0,0,40,0"  SelectionMode="Multiple"  SelectionChanged="osebe_listView_SelectionChanged" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding visible}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1AFFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ColumnDefinition}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Naziv podjetja" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding nazivPodjetja}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Ime" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ime}" Width="25"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Priimek" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding priimek}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Naslov" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding naslov}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Pošta" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding posta}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Mobilna številka" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding mobilnaSt}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Stacionarna številka" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding stacionarnaSt}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="E-naslov" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding eMail}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Skupina" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding skupina}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much! It also doesn't remove the selections, like I hoped. Why exactly is this interface needed? As far as I understand for the property to trigger an event or something like that? Sorry for my poor knowledge, I'm only a year into C# :)

Comment: It is required for change a notification to occur in a binding between a bound client and a data source as stated in the documentation on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Allright will look into it. I did, it'll show once I reach a threshhold of rep, I guess. :)