# Populating Listview based on boolean field

Tags: wpf, listview, inotifypropertychanged, listviewitem

I am trying to populate the listview based on a boolean field of each item in the list. I am not able to understand how should I going about implementing this. So, basically, the user list is being updated every time I click on ***add*** or ***delete***. However, what I am trying to do is  - NOT remove the user from the list and instead have a flag associated with each user which is set to false(*isRemoved*) once the user clicks on ***delete*** and set to true when the user clicks on ***Add***. And based on that the user will see only the items from the list whose value will be set to true. So, in a nutshell- the output of the program will be the same as my current program. Except for the fact that when a user clicks on ***Delete***, they wont be actually removing the element from the list, but would still continue to NOT see that item in the UI. Here is my an example XAML,Code Behind and Model.

***CodeBehind :***

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<User>users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        users.Add(new User() { Name = "John Smith" });
        users.Add(new User() { Name = "Brad Pitt" });

        lbUsers.ItemsSource = users;
    }

    private void btnAddUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        users.Add(new User() { Name = "New user" });
    }

    private void btnChangeUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lbUsers.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            (lbUsers.SelectedItem as User).Name = "Random Name";

        }
    }

    private void btnDeleteUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lbUsers.SelectedItem != null)
        //users.Remove(lbUsers.SelectedItem as User);
        {
            User delted = lbUsers.SelectedItem as User;
            delted.IsRemoved = true;
        }
    }
}
```

***Model:***

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private bool isRemoved;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public String Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set
        {
            if (this.name != value)
            {
                this.name = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsRemoved
    {
        get { return this.isRemoved; }
        set
        {
            if (this.isRemoved != value)
            {
                this.isRemoved = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("IsRemoved");
            }
        }
    }
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
```

}

***XAML***:

```
  <DockPanel Margin="10">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <Button Name="btnAddUser" Click="btnAddUser_Click">Add user</Button>
            <Button Name="btnChangeUser" Click="btnChangeUser_Click" Margin="0,5">Change user</Button>
            <Button Name="btnDeleteUser" Click="btnDeleteUser_Click">Delete user</Button>
        </StackPanel>

    <Border BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="1">

        <ListView Name="lbUsers">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRemoved}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"   />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>


        </ListView>
    </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: related [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068861/listview-item-visibility-based-on-boolean)

Comment: Updated the three files with the changes after referring the link. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Got it to work and updated the code above. However, when I disable the visibility, I see that it the place is left blank. I was hoping to see them in consecutive order. Updated the question with the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution to work.
 Modified the code in the question with the changes. The edit notes contains the updates.